# Django Model subset of database table

Tags: django, model, foreign-keys, relationship, admin

All of my models are not managed as they are based on a legacy database. There is a Partner master table holds amongst other things an ID, Code, Name and a PartnerTypeID which is a ForeignKey relationship with a PartnerType Table. The type of Partner can be a client, bank, etc. and each Type has a unique IDentity column, plus an Alpha Code and Name for list boxes and alike.

We then have Views that provide the rest of the system with simplified views of the Partner Data based on the Type. Therefore, we have a Client View, Bank View etc. This was done as most Partner attributes are similar across all of the various Partner types.

I can set up admin interface over the Partner table with filters etc to help data entry etc.

But I would like to know if it is possible to have a separate Django Model reflecting each partner type. Therefore, have a Client Model that only allows creation and modification of a Client Partner. I have no intention of introducing any extra attributes but simply have the Client Model only deal with Partners with a TypeID = 1, and the Bank Model only deal with TypeID = 2 etc.

I can use a database view as the model table but this would mean that the TypeID column would also need to be in the View which seems to be pointless.

Searching on SO as brought up some options using UniqueConstraints etc but the pattern doesn't seem to fit with what I am trying to achieve.

Thanks in advance